# Pandas join two dataframes based on relationship described in dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that I want to join based on a relationship described in a dictionary of lists, where the keys in the dictionary refer to ids from dfA idA column, and the items in the list are ids from dfB idB column. The dataframes and dictionary look something like this:

```
dfA
     colA    colB   idA
0    a       abc    3
1    b       def    4
2    b       ghi    5 

dfB
     colX    idB   colZ  
0    bob     7     a
1    bob     7     b
2    bob     7     c
3    jim     8     d
4    jake    9     a 
5    jake    9     e 

myDict = { '3': [ '7', '8' ], '4': [], '5': ['7', '9'] }
```

How can I use myDict to join the two dataframes to produce a dataframe like the following?

```
dfC
     colA    colB   idA   colX    idB   colZ 
0    a       abc    3     bob     7      a
1                                        b
2                                        c
3                         jim     8      d
4    b       def    4     None    None  None
5    b       ghi    5     bob     7      a
6                                        b
7                                        c
8                         jake    9      a
9                                        e
```

Comment: Is the '9' key in your dictionary supposed to be a '5'?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I've fixed the typo.

Comment: the output is wrong, jim should have idB 8, not 9, correct?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Fixed the typo.

Comment: i'm inclined to say this cannot be done, at least not with that exact format, I'm still trying to find a way

Comment: I don't think format was the point here, but the content. In case it was you could do something like this with the result from my answer: `print(result.fillna('None').groupby(['colA', 'colB', 'idA', 'idB', 'colX', 'colZ']).size().to_string())` Then get rid of the ones on the right.

Comment: @bwrabbit are the answers what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks Yuca and MJB, I've accepted MJB's answer as it seems easier to understand and works for my usecase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a linking table (DataFrame) from your dictionary. Below full working example. It might need some row and column sorting at the end to produce exactly your output.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dfA = pd.DataFrame({'colA': ('a', 'b', 'b'),
                    'colB': ('abc', 'def', 'ghi'),
                    'idA': ('3', '4', '5')})

dfB = pd.DataFrame({'colX': ('bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'jim', 'jake', 'jake'),
                    'idB': ('7', '7', '7', '8', '9', '9'),
                    'colZ': ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'e')})

myDict = {'3': ['7', '8'], '4': [], '5': ['7', '9']}

dfC = pd.DataFrame(columns=['idA', 'idB'])
i = 0
for key, value in myDict.items():
    # the if statement is for empty list to create one record with NaNs
    if not value:
        dfC.loc[i, 'idA'] = key
        dfC.loc[i, 'idB'] = np.nan
        i += 1
    for val in value:
        dfC.loc[i, 'idA'] = key
        dfC.loc[i, 'idB'] = val
        i += 1

temp = dfA.merge(dfC, how='right')
result = temp.merge(dfB, how='outer')

print(result)
```

The output is:

```
  colA colB idA  idB  colX colZ
0    a  abc   3    7   bob    a
1    a  abc   3    7   bob    b
2    a  abc   3    7   bob    c
3    b  ghi   5    7   bob    a
4    b  ghi   5    7   bob    b
5    b  ghi   5    7   bob    c
6    a  abc   3    8   jim    d
7    b  def   4  NaN   NaN  NaN
8    b  ghi   5    9  jake    a
9    b  ghi   5    9  jake    e
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not greatest solution, but it is fairly simple and gets the job done

```
temp = pd.DataFrame(dfA.idAaux.tolist(), index = dfA.idA).stack()
temp = temp.reset_index()[['idA', 0]]
temp.columns = ['idA', 'idB']
temp2 = dfA.merge(temp, left_on='idA', right_on='idA', how='left').drop('idAaux', axis=1)
temp2['idB'] = pd.to_numeric(temp2['idB']) 
res= temp2.merge(dfB, left_on='idB', right_on='idB', how='left')
```

Output:

```
colA    colB    idA idB colX    colZ
0   a   abc 3   7.0 bob a
1   a   abc 3   7.0 bob b
2   a   abc 3   7.0 bob c
3   a   abc 3   8.0 jim d
4   b   def 4   NaN NaN NaN
5   b   ghi 5   7.0 bob a
6   b   ghi 5   7.0 bob b
7   b   ghi 5   7.0 bob c
8   b   ghi 5   9.0 jake    a
9   b   ghi 5   9.0 jake    e
```